# Is "swap" an accepted alternate spelling for "swab" in Australian English?

Tags: orthography, australian-english

A client from Australia sent us some documents that pretty consistently use "alcohol swa**p**" to describe disinfecting wipes.

So no, this is not a "what do I use if I don't have gin" type of situation; they're clearly writing what I would spell as "alcohol swa**b**".

None of the dictionaries I checked has "swab" as an alternate definition of "swap", and I checked over a dozen. Is this nonetheless an accepted Australian variant, or is it a simple mistake?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem so. This is a malapropism by your client.  See below:

From Macquarie’s dictionary of Australian English - paywall, so no link.

swap

/swɒp/ (say swop)
verb (swapped, swapping)
–verb (t) 1.  to exchange, barter, or trade, as one thing for another.

–verb (i) 2.  to make an exchange.

–noun 3.  an exchange: *If you're really worried, bring along someone else's in a thermos and do a swap in the cubicle. –JOHN A SCOTT, 1988.

–phrase Colloquial 4. swap spit, (humorous) to tongue-kiss.

5. swap the witch for the bitch, to give up one addiction for another which is even worse.

Also, swop. [Middle English swappe strike, strike hands (in bargaining)]
–swapper, noun

---

swab

/swɒb/ (say swob)
noun 1.  a large mop used on shipboard for cleaning decks, etc.

2. Medicine, Veterinary Science a piece of sponge, cloth, cottonwool, or the like, often mounted on a stick, for cleansing the mouth of a sick person, or for applying medicaments, taking specimens of discharges and secretions, etc.
3. the material collected with a swab.
4. a cleaner for the bore of a firearm.
5. Colloquial a contemptible or useless person.

–verb (t) (swabbed, swabbing)
6.  to clean with or as with a swab.

7. to take up, or apply, as moisture, with or as with a swab.
8. to pass (a swab, etc.) over a surface.
9. to test (a racehorse) for possible drugging by taking a saliva sample with a swab.

Also, swob. [probably Middle Dutch swabbe mop]

Comment: Only an Aussie dictionary would reference *swap the witch for the bitch*!  Hahahahahaha